# KeyError при извлечении значения из словаря

Tags: python, словари

Пытаюсь получить значение из словаря по ключу:

```
for i in range (len(text_2)):
    out_text+=str(int(D[i]))
```

Словарь:

```
D = {
1: 'а', 2: 'А', 3: 'б', 4: 'Б', 5: 'в', 6: 'В', 7: 'г', 8: 'Г', 9: 'д', 10: 'Д',
11: 'е', 12: 'Е', 13: 'ё', 14: 'ж', 15: 'Ж', 16: 'з', 17: 'З', 18: 'и', 19: 'И', 20: 'й',
21: 'к', 22: 'К', 23: 'л', 24: 'Л', 25: 'м', 26: 'М', 27: 'н', 28: 'Н', 29: 'о', 30: 'О',
31: 'п', 32: 'П', 33: 'р', 34: 'Р', 35: 'с', 36: 'С', 37: 'т', 38: 'Т', 39: 'у', 40: 'У',
41: 'Ф', 42: 'ф', 43: 'х', 44: 'Х', 45: 'ц', 46: 'Ц', 47: 'ч', 48: 'Ч', 49: 'ш', 50: 'Ш',
51: 'щ', 52: 'Щ', 53: 'ъ', 54: 'ы', 55: 'ь', 56: 'э', 57: 'Э', 58: 'ю', 59: 'Ю', 60: 'я',
61: 'Я', 62: ' '}
```

В процессе возникает исключение `KeyError` с текстом: `KeyError: 0`. В чем причина?

Comment: у вас ключи - это символы (строки), а вы указываете ключом целое число

Comment: @etki. `out_text+=str(D[i])` Та же ошибка..

Comment: Функция range() http://pythonicway.com/education/basics/5-range дает на выходе список от 0 до указанного числа, в вашем случае от 0 до длины некой строки text_2. так что `i ` принимает как раз значения подряд от 0 до длины некоей строки. Так что не понятно что вы имеете ввиду под "значение переменной `i`" и под "порядковый номер", они в данном коде равны

Comment: @Mike А как в таком случае сделать так, чтобы за ключ принимал содержимое i?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "содержимое i" в i содержатся числа от 0 до длины строки, как я и сказал выше. В i содержится ровно то, что вы туда поместили. Если вам надо, например, брать что то из самой строки text_2 то надо это явно написать

Comment: @Mike Например, text_2=[3,6,1,3]. Как сделать, чтобы за ключи принимал числа 3,6,1,3?

Comment: Так text_2 это у вас оказывается массив ... А сложно было привести код целиком что бы это было понятно ? Если вам нужен i-й элемент text_2 так к нему и надо обращаться явно как text_2[i]

Comment: @etki ключи в словаре являются целыми числами в этом случае. Просто ключа 0 нет.

Comment: @jfs, да, с бессонницы все попутал

Answer (score 2):

На сколько я понял проблема в том что, отсчет в цикле начинается с i=0, а в словаре нет 0, начинается с 1. Стоит просто поправить словарь и начинать с 1, или сделать в теле i+1

```
D={1:'а',2:'А',3:'б',4:'Б',5:'в',6:'В',7:'г',8:'Г',9:'д',10:'Д',11:'е',12:'Е',13:'ё',14:'ж',15:'Ж',16:'з',17:'З',18:'и',19:'И',20:'й',21:'к',22:'К',23:'л',24:'Л',25:'м',26:'М',27:'н',28:'Н',29:'о',30:'О',31:'п',32:'П',33:'р',34:'Р',35:'с',36:'С',37:'т',38:'Т',39:'у',40:'У',41:'Ф',42:'ф',43:'х',44:'Х',45:'ц',46:'Ц',47:'ч',48:'Ч',49:'ш',50:'Ш',51:'щ',52:'Щ',53:'ъ',54:'ы',55:'ь',56:'э',57:'Э',58:'ю',59:'Ю',60:'я',61:'Я',62:' '}
for i in range (len(text_2)):
                print(i)
                j = i+1
                out_text+=str(D[j])
```

Я так понимаю это является решением:

```
text_2 = '3712'
out_text = ''
D={1:'а',2:'А',3:'б',4:'Б',5:'в',6:'В',7:'г',8:'Г',9:'д',10:'Д',11:'е',12:'Е',13:'ё',14:'ж',15:'Ж',16:'з',17:'З',18:'и',19:'И',20:'й',21:'к',22:'К',23:'л',24:'Л',25:'м',26:'М',27:'н',28:'Н',29:'о',30:'О',31:'п',32:'П',33:'р',34:'Р',35:'с',36:'С',37:'т',38:'Т',39:'у',40:'У',41:'Ф',42:'ф',43:'х',44:'Х',45:'ц',46:'Ц',47:'ч',48:'Ч',49:'ш',50:'Ш',51:'щ',52:'Щ',53:'ъ',54:'ы',55:'ь',56:'э',57:'Э',58:'ю',59:'Ю',60:'я',61:'Я',62:' '}
for i in range (len(text_2)):
                print(i)
                out_text+=str(D[int(text_2[i])]) #берем элемент строки по индексу и используем его как ключ для свловаря
print(out_text)
```

Comment: Теперь работает, но за ключ он принимает j.

Comment: j это просто i+1 я его добавил для наглядности. Можно просто изменить словарь, что бы ключи начинались не с 1 а с 0, тогда будет работать, без всяких j и i+1

Comment: То же самое получается.

Comment: i = 0 - это ведь порядковый номер элемента, он же существует [элемент] и не равен 0.

Comment: А если так: for i in range (1,len(text_2)+1):
                                         out_text+=str(D[i])

Comment: То же. i вместо ключа берет.

Comment: Я тогда не понимаю вопроса. i - это по сути порядковый номер элемента в строке, а выражение D[i] означает найти в словаре значение ключа, имя которого равно i. Т.е. элемент в строке под номером 1 будет соответствовать значению 'a' из словаря, так как он имеет ключ 1

Comment: Например, пользователь ввел 3 7 1 2, получается [3,7,1,2]. Разве D[0] не будет равно 'б'? Если там 3.

Comment: Значит вопрос был не совем верен и надо было больше контекста.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю это является решением:

```
text_2 = '3712'
out_text = ''
D={1:'а',2:'А',3:'б',4:'Б',5:'в',6:'В',7:'г',8:'Г',9:'д',10:'Д',11:'е',12:'Е',13:'ё',14:'ж',15:'Ж',16:'з',17:'З',18:'и',19:'И',20:'й',21:'к',22:'К',23:'л',24:'Л',25:'м',26:'М',27:'н',28:'Н',29:'о',30:'О',31:'п',32:'П',33:'р',34:'Р',35:'с',36:'С',37:'т',38:'Т',39:'у',40:'У',41:'Ф',42:'ф',43:'х',44:'Х',45:'ц',46:'Ц',47:'ч',48:'Ч',49:'ш',50:'Ш',51:'щ',52:'Щ',53:'ъ',54:'ы',55:'ь',56:'э',57:'Э',58:'ю',59:'Ю',60:'я',61:'Я',62:' '}
for i in range (len(text_2)):
                print(i)
                out_text+=str(D[int(text_2[i])]) #берем элемент строки по индексу и используем его как ключ для свловаря
print(out_text)
```